# Automatic generation of crosswords

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

When solving [crosswords](http://www.euroviakamenolomy.cz/dokumenty/verejne/Casopis/Pictures/sk070123.gif) today, I thought of if they can be generated automatically by any mathematical approach.

My question is: If database of words and any grid with some cells already filled (solution of crossword) are given, how can ML (or maybe any optimization?) be applied to generate automatically at least one crossword?

Answer (score 2):

I think a good solution would be to use [genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming). Represent each node as the position of the words in the puzzle, setting a limit on the maximum size of the puzzle. Define fitness as inversely proportional to the total size of the puzzle, and you're off to the races. Set the algorithm to end once you've achieved a certain puzzle size.

EDIT: For some reason I thought you were talking about a word search. I think a simple approach would be to fill with random words that satisfy the regular expressions defining the letters already filled in until you reach an error, backtrack to until you remove one of the letters associated with the error, and then pick up where you left off.